# sifr clipping when using filters

Tags: sifr

The left hand side of the replaced text is being clipped by a few pixels, and I can't figure it out. The only thing that seems to solve the problem is setting everything to text-align: center, but that's obviously very impractical. Not sure what I've done wrong as I can't find any reports of a similar problem.

I'm using Glow and DropShadow filters, the problem persists if any of them are used independently from the other.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offsetLeft` parameter to move the text to the right, and if necessary use `tuneWidth` to make the movie wider.

`offsetTop` and `tuneHeight` do the same for the vertical axis, and you can use negative values.